# JavaScript delete modal onclick and decrease counter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a basic inbox function. It contains 3 messages.
So I want to make that when the user click onto the DELETE button, set the msg1's display to none, and decrease the messages value.
Here is the example code:

```js
var x = 2;

function deleteMsg1() {
  
  var msg1 = document.getElementsByClassName("cont");
    if (confirm("Are you sure to want to delete this message?")) {
      msg1[0].style.display = "none";
      x = x-1;
    } else {

    }

}

function deleteMsg2() {
  
  var msg2 = document.getElementsByClassName("cont2");
    if (confirm("Are you sure to want to delete this message?")) {
      msg2[0].style.display = "none";
      x = x-1;
    } else {

    }

}

document.getElementById("msgcount").innerHTML = x;
```

```css
.cont, .cont2 {
background-color: red;
padding: 5px;
width: 100px;
margin: 25px 0;
}

.show {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>There are <span id="msgcount"></span>messages</h1>
<button onclick="deleteMsg1()">Delete</button>
<div class="cont">
  Some text...
</div>
<br><br>
<button onclick="deleteMsg2()">Delete</button>
<div class="cont2">
  Some text...
</div>
```

I know this isn’t the best idea, but I guess it’s bad.
I think I should do this with one function() and try something event listener but I don't really know how to do that.
Any idea or help?

Comment: If  you want the value to update on the display, then you will need to add `document.getElementById("msgcount").innerHTML = x; ` to both delete functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap each message's HTML in a parent element so that you can then treat each set of elements that comprise a message as a single unit and delete it all at once.

To be able to do this with a single function, you can use `this` to reference the element that triggered the callback function in the first place and [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to access the single parent wrapper.

**Notes**:

- [Do not use inline HTML event attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991), like `onclick`.
  Separate your HTML and your JavaScript and use [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
  to bind elements to event callbacks. [Even MDN recommends not using
  them.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these)
- [Do not use `.getElementsByClassName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) as it is a 25+ year old
  API that has significant performance implications. Instead, use the
  modern [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method.
- Do not use [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) if you can avoid it as it has security and
  performance implications. Since the text you are wanting to update
  doesn't have any HTML in it anyway, `.innerHTML` is not warranted.
  Instead, use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

```js
// Do your event binding in JavaScript, not HTML
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(function(element){
  element.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (confirm("Are you sure to want to delete this message?")) {
      // All you need to do is delete the nearest complete
      // ancestor message construct, which can be done with
      // the .closest() method
      this.closest(".message").remove();
      updateMessageCount();
    }
  });
});

function updateMessageCount(){
  // Set the count equal to the length of the 
  // collection returned by searching for all the
  // messages
  document.getElementById("msgcount").textContent =
       document.querySelectorAll(".message").length;
}

updateMessageCount();
```

```css
.cont, .cont2 {
background-color: red;
padding: 5px;
width: 100px;
margin: 25px 0;
}

.show {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>There are <span id="msgcount"></span> messages</h1>

<!-- By wrapping each message, you can treat all its HTML
     as one single unit. -->
<div class="message">
  <button>Delete</button>
  <div class="cont">
    Some text...
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="message">
  <button>Delete</button>
  <div class="cont">
    Some text...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is very helpful, but is there any way to keep that function when you click the delete button it'll shows you an alert like my example?

Comment: @scrummy Of course, just wrap the two lines in my `.addEventListener()` function with the same code you are using for the `if` statement. I'll update the answer to show this.

Answer (score 1):

## Explained

Here's a simple enough solution, you need to update the HTML manually every time you want to update the value of `x`. That's why I created an `updateX` function, it'll just take the value & update the DOM, it's quite that simple.

```js
const updateX = (x) => {
  document.getElementById("msgcount").innerHTML = x;
};

let x = 2;

const del = (className) => {
  const msg = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

  if (confirm("Are you sure to want to delete this message?")) {
    msg[0].style.display = "none";
    x--;
  } else {
    console.log("===");
  }

  updateX(x);
};

updateX(x);
```

```css
.cont,
.cont2 {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>There are <span id="msgcount"></span>messages</h1>
<button onclick="del('cont')">Delete</button>
<div class="cont">
  Some text...
</div>
<br/><br/>
<button onclick="del('cont2')">Delete</button>
<div class="cont2">
  Some text...
</div>
```

Comment: No worries, glad I could help! :)

Comment: This solution doesn't work. The count is inaccurate and multiple delete buttons persist after deleting all the messages. Additionally, it uses old, outdated APIs.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I get your point, I just tried to keep it as close to the solution that the OP provided as possible really... At least from a functional level anyway! 

Comment: But, as I said, it doesn't work. After deleting a message, the delete button still exists. If you delete a message, it's delete button should be deleted as well. Also, if you keep clicking the button, the message count goes negative.

Answer (score 1):

My advice to you: **Never** declare **events js** inside `html` structure `tags`! As here:

```
<button onclick="deleteMsg1()">Delete</button>
```

This is a very **bad practice**. This has many disadvantages. And this can lead to bad consequences.

I made a solution for you with the `forEach()` method, without using javascript in `html`.

The **Delete** button is also removed.

```js
let msg = document.querySelectorAll(".cont");
let btn_del = document.querySelectorAll('.btn_del');
let x = 2;

btn_del.forEach(function (btn_del_current, index) {
    btn_del_current.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (confirm("Are you sure to want to delete this message?")) {
            this.style.display = "none";
            msg[index].style.display = "none";
            x = x - 1;
            document.getElementById("msgcount").innerHTML = x;
        } else {}
    });
});
```

```css
.cont, .cont2 {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>There are <span id="msgcount"></span>messages</h1>
<button class="btn_del">Delete</button>
<div class="cont">
  Some text...
</div>
<br><br>
<button class="btn_del">Delete</button>
<div class="cont">
  Some text...
</div>
```